# Why am I able to assign char* value to a string?

Tags: c

```
int y = 5;
int *x = &y;
```

Pointer holds an address value like above...

.

```
char *y = "Hello World!";
char *x = &y;
```

But how come char doesn't work that way?

```
char *x = "Hello";
```

Above code works but how come pointer x is able to store a value of string instead of an address?

Comment: Observation: your user name is not one that makes people want to help you.

Comment: Your initial example of characters doesn't work; `char y = "Hello World!";` is a major type mismatch (pointer assigned to `char`).  If you had `char y = 'H';`, you could use `char *x = &y;` — that is legitimate (though `y` does not point to a character string; it only points to a single character).  Strings are arrays of characters with a null terminator.

Comment: I used to think stack overflow was for brain-damaged people. Then I got an actual brain injury and I'm totally convinced it's awesome now. True story. :D

Comment: A `char* x` can only store the address of a single character. However, by [C string convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling), functions access that character and the ones immediately after it in memory until they find `\0` characters. In other words, you just point at the starting character of the string, and functions know to look for the rest.

Comment: Seriously though, SO is useful. Most of the questions may be trivial and even stupid, but its a pretty good corpus of peer reviewed code snippets and solutions, and I think of answering as helping to build it (if I don't do it just for the fun of it).  But I totally get how someone can "hate SO". :D

Comment: @PSkocik   They can when they are pissed off by not getting their homework done here .

Comment: My username is nothing more than just an 'Attention' getter. More attention = more clicks = more answers...

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char *y = "Hello World!";
> char *x = &y;
> ```

`&y` is a `char**` (a pointer to a pointer to a `char`), not a `char*` (a pointer to a `char`).  You cannot assign a `char**` to a `char*`, and vice versa.  They point at two different things.

> But how come char doesn't work that way?
>
> ```
> char *x = "Hello";
> ```

`"Hello"` is a **string literal**.  It is implemented as a `char[]` array in static (read-only) memory.  An array can *decay* into a pointer of the same base type.  However, note that in this example, assigning a string literal to a **non-const** `char*` pointer is **deprecated** in modern versions of C++.  Older versions allowed it for backwards compatibility with C.  In modern C++ versions, you need to use a **const** `char*` pointer instead:

```
const char *y = "Hello World!";
const char *x = y;
```

Otherwise, you can make a copy of the literal into a **non-const** `char[]` array and decay that into a **non-const** `char*` pointer:

```
char y[] = "Hello World!";
char *x = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

The char* is just an address, not actually space to store data. Before you can store the string, you would have to allocate the space by using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

The `"Hello"` literal won't be created on the stack. It will be stored in the static read only section of the compiled object file or binary and `char *x` will be just a pointer to it. It won't store the string.
That assignment is only possible in C, though, I believe, because of its weak type checking.
In C++ you'd only be able to make the assignment to a `const char*` variable.

This:

```
char x[] = "Hello";
```

will actually store the string in a char array on the stack and the array doesn't need to be `const`.

`strcpy`ing the string literal into `malloc`ed memory will also do to if you want a writable version of the string literal.

---

Anyway, this buggy code:

```
char y = "Hello World!";
char *x = &y;
```

Will actually compile in `gcc` but with a warning. The string literal will autoconvert to an `char *` pointer, which autoconverts to an integer, which autoconverts (badly) to char, but it's totally not what you want.

Comment: So when using `char*`, it should be `const` so that I don't lose my string `Hello`?

Comment: It should be const because if it isn't, the compiler won't warn you against writing into what it points to. And if you do write into what it points to, the operating system will usually kill you with a SEGFAULT because you'll be writing into memory marked read-only.

Comment: Note that older C++ versions allowed assigning a string literal to a non-const `char*` pointer, for backwards compatibility with C.  It is only modern C++ versions (C++11 and later) that deprecate this assignment, making you use a `const char*` pointer instead.